# A new web app from scratch on the Microsoft stack (Core/4.6) and web client technologies

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

We are about to begin developing a new big web application from scratch, and we have some uncertainty regarding the path to take with the Microsoft stack. Can a new application (enterprise scale) can be created with the new .NET CORE stack (i.e. ASP.NET CORE, MVC 6, EF 7 etc.) and will prove stable and performant? Meaning, is it ready for production use?

That is on the server side. We have the same uncertainty regarding the client side technologies. Angular 2 is also not in a finished state. We don't know if it can be used in production or not. Same with React. We are probably not going to use Knockout as it seems that it is not heavily developed anymore (but maybe I'm wrong).

So, to sum it up, we really want to use .NET CORE and Angular 2/React, but is it a good idea to use them in their current state?

Thanks a lot,

ashilon

Comment: This question asks for the opinions of others rather than for a factual answer to a question.  You might try refrasing the question to ask for specific examples of sites using ASP.NET CORE or Angular 2/React that are are serving some specific amount of requests per day or greater.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I'm just asking for a suggestion. Is it too much to ask? Where can I ask for this information if not in SO?

Comment: ashilon - It's not too much to ask.  You can totally ask on SO, I'm just suggesting that you tweak the question so that it can be objectively answered with facts. A question requesting specific examples of other sites doing X requests per day or greater using ASP.NET Core or Angular 2 would I think get you the info you want and it could be objectively answered with facts.  Without that, anyone can answer and say "Yep, it's ready for large enterprise use" but what does that mean, enterprises come in all sizes and have all kinds of workloads.

Comment: I see what you're saying Ron C, but my question is really very simple. I simply want to know if Core RC2 is ready for production (more so in terms of breaking changes). Microsoft doesn't state that on their sites. I thought that SO would help. Thanks anyway Ron C. I don't know how else I can tweak the question. And personally (no one's watching you know) I don't like it that people down vote your question because they don't know how to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were lots of breaking changes between ASP.NET Core RC1 and RC2. Microsoft is trying to minimize breaking changes for the outer surface area of the asp.net core framework from here on out but even after saying that they announced that project.json is going away in favor of a msbuild based approach. They plan to ship a conversion tool but that's futureware.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/05/23/changes-to-project-json/

Also, you can see from the asp/announcements area of github that there have been 10 braking changes under the hood in the last two weeks.  More are sure to come.  https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues

With regard to customers using asp.net core for large scale projects, the massive online game "Age of Assent" is using it and has been a major OSS contributor to Kestrel. Here is a link to a video that gives a good highlight of what they are doing and it's all based on ASP.NET Core (as mentioned at the end of the video)  It's pretty impressive stuff.  http://web.ageofascent.com/category/development/aspnet-5/

I think you will find that it's a mixed bag with regard to ASP.NET Core right now.  There are certainly some developers building impressive web applications with ASP.NET core now, but remember this software is still pre-release and breaking changes are still occurring.  Additionally the Visual Studio 2015 tooling for ASP.NET Core is only in preview at this point, so it's pretty rough.

Even referencing a 3rd party dll for which you don't have the source code can be challenging at this point (RC2). See here for more detail:  https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/45

Hope that helps.

Comment: Now that was informative! Thanks a bunch mate!

Comment: My pleasure, glad to be of help.